# aws cloudformation list-stacks gives me duplicate stacks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I run this to get a list of my CF stacks:

```
aws cloudformation list-stacks --region us-east-1
```

I seem to be getting multiple results for the same stacks. I seems like its returning every *version* of each stack? How do I just get one result for each stack?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What makes you to think it returns duplicate stack names? Are there more than 100 stacks? The following should give just the stack names and should include the latest version.

```
aws cloudformation list-stacks --region us-east-1 --query 'StackSummaries[].StackName'
```

or to get the stack status:

```
aws cloudformation list-stacks --region us-east-1 --query 'StackSummaries[].[StackName,StackStatus]' --output text
```

To get only the stack with running stacks:

```
--stack-status-filter CREATE_COMPLETE
```

For more info: [aws cloudformation list-stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/list-stacks.html)

You can use JMESPATH in `--query` to exclude stacks in certain states. Easiest way is to use `grep`.

```
aws cloudformation list-stacks --region us-east-1 --query 'StackSummaries[].[StackName,StackStatus]' --output text | grep -v DELETE_COMPLETE
```

To exclude multiple status:

```
aws cloudformation list-stacks --region us-east-1 --query 'StackSummaries[].[StackName,StackStatus]' --output text | egrep -v 'DELETE_COMPLETE| CREATE_COMPLETE| UPDATE_COMPLETE'
```

Comment: I get a bunch of stacks with the same name when i run that

Comment: ah there is many with `"DELETE_COMPLETE"` how do I get currently running stacks only?

Comment: coooool can i use a bool? `status != DELETE_COMPLETE`

Comment: @red888 my updated solution has a simple way to get what you want.

Comment: hmm almost, can I have an OR? CREATE_COMPLETE OR UPDATE_COMPLETE. many stack are in the update_complete status

Comment: You can exclude the stacks are deleted by updating the query parameter. Your command will look like: `aws cloudformation list-stacks --region us-east-1 --query 'StackSummaries[?starts_with(StackStatus, \`DELETE_COMPLETE\`) != \`true\`].[StackName,StackStatus]' --output text`

Comment: You can use stack status filter parameter to filter the stacks. Below command lists only stacks that are in Create complete state.                                                        aws cloudformation list-stacks --stack-status-filter CREATE_COMPLETE

Comment: @red888 see my update to use `egrep`. Your question now becomes `unix` question, nothing to do AWS.

Comment: @helloV - `egrep -v` is for exclusions. In this case stacks in `CREATE_COMPLETE` or `UPDATE_COMPLETE` will be excluded. We should either remove `-v` and `DELETE_COMPLETE` from egrep command or have another pipe.

Comment: It is possible to pass multiple values to `--stack-status-filter`. It's a more readable syntax than adding to the query. But using the query might more preferable if only trying to remove deleted stacks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no conception of stack versions in CloudFormation. `aws cloudformation list-stacks` does not return duplicate stacks.

What happened is you probably had many stacks share the same name. For example, you can create a stack named "Stack1", delete it, and create a new stack with the same name "Stack1". Those 2 stacks will have different IDs, but will appear when calling `list-stacks`. The first one will have status `DELETE_COMPLETE` and have a different ID than the second stack.